# Git: how do *you* use it?/dummies tutorial

Tags: git, macos, github

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)

With git, how do people use it? I mean do you have to use the terminal all the time, or is there a slightly more user friendly way of doing it?

Or is there a tutorial for a complete newcomer to VCS and git?

Comment: You might want to see this post from the FAQ tab: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide

Comment: Seconding the link posted by Mike as a good source of general "getting started" info.

Comment: Hackr has a pretty good "collection" of GIT tutorials, which I personally found useful while I was learning GIT - http://hackr.io/tutorials/git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Github to store, share, and manage small things - like, say your dotfiles - is a pretty good way to get a feel for how you might use git. They also have an extremely useful [help page](http://help.github.com/), which in turn links to a [crash course](http://gitref.org/) on git.

The book [Pro Git](http://progit.org/book/) is also online for free in its entirety, and includes a getting started guide, as well as an introduction to version control.

Answer (score 1):

I always use Gitgui (which comes with Git). I think the only exception is sometimes I'll create the repository on the command line.